# Saving files and preserving order during retrieve

Tags: java, android

In my note taking app, as soon as user adds a note, I save it using using the following code :

```
public void saveNote(String note, String noteCreationDate) {

        // Name file with current date
        FileOutputStream outputStream;

        try {
            outputStream = openFileOutput(noteCreationDate, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write(note.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

However when I load the notes using

```
String[] allNotes = fileList();
```

then iterate one by one and add it to List and attach it to adapter, the order of the items in the RecyclerView is changed.

How do I preserve the order.

thanks

Comment: Hello @32a. Could you, please, provide more description of what is not working? Have you considered to use another store method, like a `SharedPreferences` or a database (SQLite, Room)?

Comment: Im using files for storage, its just that, the order in which its stored and diplayed, is not preserved, when you close the app and reload using the logic I provided in qn

Comment: The [official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#fileList()) does not specify the order that the files are returned from the `fileList()` method.

Comment: Yes. how do I fix it.

Comment: Is there a requirement to store that in the file storage instead of using a database or `SharedPreferences`? It would be very easier to guarantee the stored order if you store in a database like [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room).

Comment: Its the way its designed it. I dont want to switch now. Is there a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better solution is to store the notes in a more appropriate way, like `SharedPreferences` or a database.

As a workaround, you can sort the file names obtained from `fileList()` method.

```
String[] allNotes = fileList();
Arrays.sort(allNotes);

// Iterate over the files
```

You also should use the file names with a proper date format, like [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601): `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'` to guarantee the alphabetical order.